# Python Not Clicking in game or Webbrowser

Tags: python, mouse, pyautogui

I am making my own autoclicker. But its can not clicking. I try all alternatives which ones in stackoverflow. Is there a any helper please.

My Code:

```
import pyautogui
import python_imagesearch.imagesearch
import time

while True:
    icon = python_imagesearch.imagesearch.imagesearch("clickme.png", 0.8)
    print(icon)
    icon_x = icon[0]
    icon_y = icon[1]
    icon_x = icon_x+5
    icon_y = icon_y+5
    # time.sleep(1.5)
    pyautogui.leftClick(icon_x, icon_y)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.leftClick(icon_x, icon_y)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I am trying the click here.
https://www.tetralark.com/ClickerJs/

It's solved. It is about other games anticheat blocking.

Comment: If you got any errors pls post it here. Also I don't think there is a left click function like the one u used. Check this https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html. You have to move to that position and do a left click

Comment: No i do not getting any errors. It is moving on my image but it is not clicking. with this code which one i posted. @PranavKumar

Comment: Try replacing left Click with this pyautogui.click(x=icon_x, y=icon_y).  I'm pretty sure your left Click function is the problem. I couldn't find that function in the documentation.

Comment: It is not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

If your code is moving to your image already, you can click in the image by using:

```
pyautogui.click()
```

Or you can pass coordinates as [Mouse Control Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) says:

```
pyautogui.click(x=100, y=200)  # move to 100, 200, then click the left mouse button.
```